# Why doesn't Banshee recognize my video mp4 files?

Tags: 11.04, video, banshee

Avi files placed in the Video folder show up almost immediately, but for some reason, mp4's do not.

Movie Player will play the mp4's, so I don't think it is a gstreamer situation.

Comment: What type of video codec is in the .mp4 container?

Comment: Can you open the files in Banshee at all?  Is this issue specific to importing with the library watcher, or does Banshee completely not recognize these files?  Also, the log in ~/.config/banshee-1/ might be helpful.

Comment: Nautilus properties says its an h.264/AVC with AAC audio. It does not appear to be a 'watch folder' situation, because I dropped an xvid into my Video folder, and Banshee saw it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug discussed [here](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/iphone-video-compatibility-problem-td2998763.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I always do for the ultimate codec support:

```
sudo wget http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/`lsb_release -cs`.list --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list; sudo apt-get -q update; sudo apt-get --yes -q --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring; sudo apt-get -q update


sudo apt-get install non-free-codecs
```